# UIImagePickerController - animate taken photo into on-screen thumbnail

Tags: ios, animation, uiimagepickercontroller

My app lets the user take photos. After the user has taken a photo with a `UIImagePickerController`, which my main view controller presents modally, I would like to perform an animation where the photo just taken "shrinks and moves into place" to a preset thumbnail slot, somewhere in the main view of the view controller beneath.

I guess the best way to do it would be to, after the user takes the picture and chooses "Use":

1. Setup a `UIImageView` with the photo just taken at full screen size (to match the after-shot preview of the UIImagePickerController),
2. Add the image view as subview of the initial, still hidden view controller's main view,
3. Dismiss the `UIImagePickerController` with animation, but with cross disolve transition style (I wonder if I can present with one style -the default `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`- and dismiss with another. Haven't tried yet).
4. Animate the "shrinking into place" of the image view.

I haven't tried this yet, but, **perhaps there's a better/smarter way?**

The hardest parts would seem to be placing the image view **exactly** to match the preview in the picker controller (pixel perfect), so that the dismissal is seamless. On the plus side, the app is iPad landscape only, so that should simplify things a bit.

Comment: Did you find a better/smarter way?

Comment: No, I haven't found any.